# Tag merge request: 4kb-sector into advanced-format

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[4kb-sector](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/4kb-sector) is a duplicate of [advanced-format](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/advanced-format) and should be merged into the latter - perhaps retaining 4kb-sector as a synonym of advanced-format, as some people may not know the [Advanced Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format) term.

Comment: You may want to consider editing the tag wiki for [tag:advanced-format] so it's more clear exactly what it means. I believe at your rep you can propose edits and someone will be happy to approve it :)

Comment: now done, have a look.

Comment: much better :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea -- this is now complete!

https://serverfault.com/tags/synonyms